# Why can I access the private variable in this case?

Tags: java, variables, private

I have private int a variable and I access to this variable via test.a. Why this is ok? I thought that this way is possible only if I had public int a variable, not private.

```
public class Test {

    private int a;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test(5);
        System.out.println(test.a);
    }

    public Test (int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: The method name `Test` is kind of confusing.  Essentially, it is a setter. I would suggest you change it to `setA`.

Comment: That's a constructor, not a method. No other way to define a constructor. The name matching the class and the lack of a return type are how you can tell it's a constructor.

Comment: Yes, it is a constructor, it is not setter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access it because your `main` method is in the same class.

Comment: Yup... But this requires some expansion ;) More specifically, a `private` variable can be accessed from anywhere within the same class, and this includes inner classes as well.

Comment: Thanks! I didn´t know that this is possible in this case.

Answer (score 5):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) :

> The private modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed in its own class.

This includes everything you can have in a class : static methods, inner classes (static or not), anonymous classes, ...

Comment: Note that an instance (non-static) member cannot be accessed from within a static member. The reason `test.a` can be accessed is that `test` is a local variable, and does not refer to the class `Test`.